# Multi line regex match until next group is found

Tags: regex

I am trying to match text in license files, and I am getting stuck on how to stop matching any text when the next match is found.

My text looks like this:

```
packagename
1.0.5 <https://github.com/user/packagename>

Lots of text
here
across multiple lines

packagename2
1.1.0 <https://github.com/user/packagename2>

lots more text here
this continues for a while
across many lines
```

To find where each match should start, I use the following regex:

[`(\w+\n\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s<.*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/Vobnml/5)

This matches all of my headers correctly, but when I try to use:

[`(\w+\n\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s<.*>)((.|\n)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Vobnml/6)

To match all characters and newlines following, it only captures the first group, and then just all text after.

I want to match the package name as one group, and everything before the next package name as a second group.

Comment: Are you using it in Python? Then use [`(?m)^(\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s+<.*>)([\s\S]*?)(?=[\n\r]+\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s<|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/R5MFq7/1)

Comment: Yes, my fault, forgot to tag that.  Works perfectly btw, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^(\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s+<.*>)([\s\S]*?)(?=[\n\r]+\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s<|\Z)
```

In Python,

```
results = re.findall(r'^(\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s+<.*>)([\s\S]*?)(?=[\n\r]+\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s<|\Z)', re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R5MFq7/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line (due to `re.M` modifier, `^` matches the line start in addition to start of the string)
- `(\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s+<.*>)` - Group 1:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\n` - a newline
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+){2}` - 2 repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `<.*>` - `<`, and 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible, `>`
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of...
- `(?=[\n\r]+\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s<|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that matches without adding to the match value

  - `[\n\r]+` - 1+ line break chars followed with
  - `\w+\n\d+(?:\.\d+){2}\s<` - Group 1 pattern (almost all of it, you may add it all here, but it seems thatup to `<` is enough)
- `|` - or
- `\Z` - very end of string.

Comment: If there is any issue with the pattern please let know, as [OP confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679472/multi-line-regex-match-until-next-group-is-found/49679596#comment86370814_49679472), this solution is working "perfectly".